# Wordpress wp_dequeue not removing js from head

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to clean up the head of a website. I have a photo gallery plugin being used on a single page but the plugin is sticking the js in the head of every page. I've located the line of code in the plug-in editor that adds the code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts');
```

I know it's this because when I remove it and refresh my page, all the tags are gone.
I added this to `functions.php`:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'bwg_front_end_scripts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

I figured this would work, but it doesn't. I've put it at the top of my functions.php and the bottom. I've tried a bunch of other options too but nothing seems to work.

Comment: sorry, better @user2864740?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `remove_action()` here in place of your function.

**Excluding from all single pages:**

If you use `!is_page()`, you will be excluding it from all single pages.

```
if (!is_page()) {
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts', 100 );
}
```

**Excluding from all pages not using a particular page template:**

If you need to target one specific page, I'd recommend targeting your page by it's template using `is_page_template()` rather than `is_page()`. `is_page_template()` checks if the current page is using the specified page template. If the page template is in the theme root, you just need to pass the filename:

```
if (!is_page_template('templates/your_gallery_page_template.php')) {
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts', 100 );
}
```

**Excluding from all pages except a specific post ID:**

```
if (!is_page( 42 )) { // When Page 42 (ID) is not being displayed.
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts', 100 );
}
```

**Excluding from all pages except a specific page title:**

```
if (!is_page( 'Gallery' )) { // When the Page with a post_title of "Gallery" is not being displayed.
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts', 100 );
}
```

**Reference:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Now I've got to figure out how to keep it loading on the one page.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try the new code and see if it works for you.

Comment: So your code works great for all pages, but I am trying to keep it loading on the page where the gallery is located. I tried: `if (!is_page(gallery)) { remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts', 100 ); }` but that didn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer. I don't know your page template filename, so I cannot post working code. You'll need to update it yourself.

Comment: I couldn't get the script to only load on the gallery page through functions.php so I placed `remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts' )` in functions.php and then added a php if statement to my footer for the gallery page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm you intend for this to work on just pages and not posts?

You're mistaking an action for a script.

Replace your code in functions.php with this instead.

```
// Only apply if not on a single page.
if ( ! is_page() ) {
    // Remove the plugins enqueue action.
    remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to remove it from EVERYTHING except for a single page which uses the slug 'gallery'. I tried `if ( ! is_page('gallery') ) { remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bwg_front_end_scripts');
}` but that didn't work.